Cocycles of an Algebra with linear maps between two specific vector spaces as coefficients
I encountered the concept of “cocycle” in Problem 2.21 of Introduction to Representation Theory by Etingof et al. In the book, every algebra considered is associative with a unit, and the field is assumed to be algebraically closed.
The problem is about extensions of representations of an algebra $A$ over a field $k$. Given two $A$-modules $V$ and $W$, a representation of $A$ on $V\oplus_k W$ is called an extension of $W$ by $V$ if the sequence
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow V\rightarrow V\oplus_k W\rightarrow W\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
is a short exact sequence of $A$-modules.
Such an extension can be identified with a linear map $f: A\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_k(W,V)$ that satisfies $f(ab)=f(a)\circ b+a\circ f(b)$. Linear maps $f$ that satisfy this condition are called $1$-cocycles of $A$ with coefficients in $\operatorname{Hom}_k(W,V)$, and they form a vector space denoted by $Z^1(W,V)$.
There is also a coboundary operator defined on $\operatorname{Hom}_k(W,V)$, which maps a linear transformation $X$ to a $1$-cocycle $dX: a\mapsto a\circ X-X\circ a$. These coboundaries form a subspace $B^1(W,V)\subset Z^1(W,V)$. The quotient space $\operatorname{Ext}^1(W,V) := Z^1(W,V)/B^1(W,V)$ then "classifies" extensions of $W$ by $V$.
My question is: what exactly is the cochain complex here?

A similar problem appears in Algebra by Serge Lang, specifically in Exercise 27, titled “Extensions of Modules.” of Chapter XX. For more context and details on this topic, one might find it helpful to refer to the chapter on “General Homology Theory” in that book.
